# Please explain this snippet of code (return statement)

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having trouble deciphering this bit of code. I've encountered a return statement as complicated as this, so can someone break it down for me? (This code was from a problem in which I had to differentiate between a leap year and a non-leap year). Thanks!

```
return ((year % 4) || (!(year % 100) && ((year+300) % 400))) ? 28 : 29;
```

Comment: It's a ternary expression determining days for february and checks for leap years or not.

Comment: Seriously, download a copy of the C or C++ operator precedence table, and work through it yourself. There are unnecessary parentheses in that code and I'm not sure about the `year+300` part: looks wrong to me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : but it's doing it wrong - it claims 2000 was not a leap year eg., and that 2100 will be a leap year.

Comment: @Bathsheba - extra parentheses may be unnecessary, but state clearly your intent.

Comment: The whole rule as I recall should be a leap year every 4 years but not on the even hundredth year, except if it's the even 400th year in which case there is a leap day again.

Comment: I disagree: extra parentheses make me think there is something funky going on. Memorise that operator precedence table! The formula is incorrect anyway. Perhaps too many parentheses have obscured things.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a conditional expression, `condition ? true_value : false_value`.

It gets clearer if you separate out the condition:

```
bool not_leap_year = (year % 4) || (!(year % 100) && ((year+300) % 400)); 
return not_leap_year ? 28 : 29;
```

It's more common to compute the negation of the condition though, as the rules for when there *is* a leap year are better known than the rules for when there isn't (so there's less chance of bugs).

```
bool leap_year = year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
return leap_year ? 29 : 28;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
((year % 4) || (!(year % 100) && ((year+300) % 400))) ? 28 : 29;
```

This is the ternary operator `?` with a relatively complex boolean expression. You could achieve the same with an if expression:

```
if ( (year % 4) // year not dividable by 4
     or
     (
        not (year % 100) // year dividable by 100
        and
        ((year+300) % 400))) // year + 300 not dividable by 400
{
  return 28;
}
else
{
  return 29;
}
```

One can make that a bit more readable using a helper function:

```
bool dividableBy(unsigned value, unsigned divisor) {
  return value % divisor == 0;
}

//...
if ((not dividableBy(year, 4)) or
    (dividableBy(year, 100) and
     (not dividableBy(year+300, 400)))) {
  return 28;
}
else {
  return 29;
}
```